# run code in background in swift 2

Tags: swift

**Hello**

i want execute below code every 60 second in background to check if have update in database and server:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://.........")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "cardnumber=\(txtCardNamber.text)&mobile=\(txtMobileNamber.text)"

    //let postString = "cardnumber=\(txtCardNamber.text)&mobile=\(txtMobileNamber.text)"


    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }



        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let asr = responseString
        print("Holol ID = \(asr)")
        //var asrlen = asr?.length

        //var ss = asr!.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: asrlen!))

    }
    task.resume()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put that code up there into an function named "`update`", you can use NSTimer:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

(where `timer` is a strong class property, so ARC won't happily release it after you set it up).

[Here is a tutorial](https://www.weheartswift.com/nstimer-in-swift/) that might help.

Comment: Thanks .. But i want service work whenever close app